# Calculation errors in Time Program

Tags: java, class, loops

still working on this stupid Time Program.... My new problem is in the calculation, the minuts don't seem to be adding to the total and I'm not sure why... any inout would be greatly appreciated as always :)

```
public  class Time {

    public int Minutes, Hours, TotalMin;
    private String  correctedMinutes ;
    public String valid, TimeofDay;
    public String error, noerror;


    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Sets up the time by defining its minutes and hours 
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

public Time() {
    this.Hours = 0;
    this.Minutes = 0;}

public Time(int hour, int minute, String timeofday) {
    this.Hours = hour;
    this.Minutes = minute;
    this.TimeofDay = timeofday;}


public String testTimeofDay ( String timeofday)

{ 
    if  (TimeofDay.equals ("AM")) {TimeofDay="AM";
         return "";}

     else if (TimeofDay.equals("PM")) {TimeofDay="PM";
         return "";}

        else {TimeofDay="AM";
        return "Invalid Entry: AM/PM";}
    }

public String testHoursMinutes(int hours, int minutes)

{
    if (Minutes>59|| Minutes<0||Hours>23 || Hours<0) 
        {Minutes=0;
        Hours=0;
        TimeofDay="AM";
        return "Invalid Entry: Incorrect Value";}

            else {Hours=hours;
            Minutes=minutes;
            return "";}



}


public int addMinutes (int hours, int minutes, int elapsedMin)
    { 
        if (elapsedMin<0)
            TotalMin=minutes;

            else {
            TotalMin=elapsedMin+Minutes;}

            return TotalMin;}

public String ConvertMintoHour (int hours, int minutes){        
        while (TotalMin>60)
            {TotalMin=TotalMin-60;
            Hours=Hours+1;   
            if (Hours==13)
             { Hours=0;

             Minutes=TotalMin;
             }}
return(Hours+ " " +Minutes);




    }   
public String toString ()
        {
            String correctedMinutes = String.format("%02d", Minutes);
            return (Hours+ ":" + correctedMinutes + TimeofDay);     }





}
```

And here is the test code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TimeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


int minutes, hours, elapsedMin; 
String timeofday, startTime;

Scanner scan=new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter starting hour (1-12):");
hours=scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter starting minute (0-59):");
minutes=scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter AM or PM:");
timeofday=scan.next();


Time classtime = new Time (hours, minutes, timeofday);

System.out.println(classtime.testTimeofDay(timeofday));
System.out.println(classtime.testHoursMinutes (hours, minutes));
 System.out.println(classtime.toString());


System.out.print("The class begins at ");
System.out.println (classtime.toString());

startTime=classtime.toString();

System.out.println("Enter a time in minutes representing the class duration:");
elapsedMin=scan.nextInt();

classtime.addMinutes (hours, minutes, elapsedMin);
System.out.println ("Class End Time:" + classtime.toString());


System.out.print(elapsedMin + " minutes after "+ startTime + " is ");
System.out.println (classtime.toString());





System.out.print("The class ends at ");
System.out.println (classtime.toString());


System.out.print("The class ends at ");

System.out.print("MILITARY");
}}
```

Comment: If you know that the error is with you tallying up minutes, then it's probably not a bad idea to post just that bit of code, and perhaps a pruned down version of whatever that's calling it. It'll help you find the issue, plus make things easier for us if you're still stuck.

Comment: sorry, Ive had a few problems than ran deeper than I expected so I figured it wouldnt hurt to just put it all.

Comment: No, no, posting it all is generally not a good idea, especially if it's huge.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but it seems weird to me, you seem to be adding `TotalMin`, which never effects `Minutes` and is never used in any of your output?

Comment: thank you so much, there were a bunch of issues but I think I got em!

Comment: You seem to be a beginner programmer... Please take your time and think about each method in your timer and how to make it better - most importantly by making it simplier. [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) should always be followed.

Answer (score 1):

In method `String ConvertMintoHour (int hours, int minutes)`. Change your condition from

```
while (TotalMin>60)
```

To

```
while (TotalMin>59)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of issues, but lets start with the `addMinutes` method...

```
public int addMinutes(int hours, int minutes, int elapsedMin) {
    if (elapsedMin < 0) {
        TotalMin = minutes;
    } else {
        TotalMin = elapsedMin + Minutes;
    }

    return TotalMin;
}
```

Basically, `hours` and `minutes` are never, make no sense and should be discarded.

You add `elapsedMin` to `TotalMin` but it is never used to produce the output.

Instead, you should apply the values back to the `Hours` and `Minutes` variables, for example...

```
public int addMinutes(int elapsedMin) {

    int time = (Hours * 60) + Minutes;
    time += elapsedMin;

    Hours = time / 60;
    time = time % 60;
    Minutes = time;

    return time;

}
```

This concept could also be applied to your `ConvertMintoHour` method ;)

A simpler solution would be to manage the internal concept of the time as the number of minutes since midnight.

This would allow you to simple add or subtract minutes from your "Time" class.  When you were ready, you could use the above algorithm to generate the hours and minutes you need to generate your output...IMHO

I'm sure someone else has already pointed this out to you, but you should take the time to read through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), it will help make you code easier to read for other developers ;)

Answer (score 0):

The method `ConvertMintoHour` can be written simply as follows:

```
public String ConvertMintoHour() {
        int noOfHrs = TotalMin / 60;
        Hours = (Hours + noOfHrs) % 13;
        Minutes = TotalMin % 60;
        return Hours + " " + Minutes;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work.  I don't think you need to add the `Hours` into the `Hours`, simply take the `TotalMin`.  Using `% 13` throws the calculation off, if I use a `TotalMin` of `930`, it returns `2 30` instead of `3 30`